# Convert string 1k string to 1000 number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an amount field it can accept numbers like 5000 and strings like 1k,2m, 2.5k etc, so I need to convert the strings like:

```
 1k => 1000
 2m => 2000000
 2.5k => 2500
```

And so on. How is this possible in JavaScript?

Answer (score 14):

Okay, sorry about the misunderstanding.

```
function getVal (val) {
  multiplier = val.substr(-1).toLowerCase();
  if (multiplier == "k")
    return parseFloat(val) * 1000;
  else if (multiplier == "m")
    return parseFloat(val) * 1000000;
}
```

**Output**

```
getVal("5.5k");
5500
getVal("2k");
2000
getVal("3.2m");
3200000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
var multipliers = {k: 1000, m: 1000000};
var string = '2.5k';
console.log(parseFloat(string)*multipliers[string.charAt(string.length-1).toLowerCase()]);
```

That should print 2500 from 2.5k.